# Rule for .htaccess not works

Tags: .htaccess

I'm starting with a project buy I need to show my url without stranges caracteres like "?="...
I'm trying to construct my .htaccess but never works!

Actually I've:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteBase /    
RewriteRule ^product/(.+)$ index.php?section=details&product=$1
</IfModule>
```

But, if I try to open a url like

```
localhost/project/shop/product/myproduct
```

What I worte wrong in the file?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a RewriteRule expert but your regex `RewriteRule ^product/(.+)$ index.php?section=details&product=$1` starts with "product" and the url you test with "project"

Comment: Where is your htaccess located ? In which folder ?

Comment: @JuniusRendel this is only my url to access in my project my base url is localhost/project/shop/... I don't know if my RewriteBase it's good in my htaccess file... :S

Comment: My htaccess it's in /shop/ folder @JustinIurman